# Console output not aligned on 4k screen

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, console, display, graphics

After a fresh Ubuntu Server install, the console (no GUI) output is not aligned to the left side of my 4k screen. Instead, each line starts at a third of the screen width away from the right side, and then overflows to the left side of the screen.

This doesn't seem to be a problem with lower-resolution screens (tested on 1440p). My GPU is an AMD Radeon HD 8490.

I have a picture here: [image: photo of screen showing the issue]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your card might not be able to drive that monitor. 4K seems to be a common barrier, even for some 3-y.o. cards.